# Session gets clear in category page only in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, session, cookie

I have one problem in Magento Live server uploaded site. The problem is related to session or cookies. When I add product to cart or login, then visit category page, the session gets clear and i get signed out and cart gets cleared.

I tried setting session/cookie management. but I did not find a solution. Also asked to server technical support, they also were not able to find anything. This only happens in only one category page.

Anybody else has faced this problem?

Please give me solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If a session is already set, once a visitor visits your Magento website then Magento does not set it's own session data - as per my post here: https://www.creare.co.uk/session-error-in-magento

If it's only happening on one category page then you've got an issue somewhere else - make sure you're not setting any session variables anywhere external to your Magento site and accidentally carrying them across